# errors with reactive forms in angular after restarting the server

Tags: angular

errors with reactive forms in angular after restarting the server

this is my code

in app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './account/register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './account/login/login.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './shared/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './shared/footer/footer.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in the registration component .ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder,  FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  registrationForm: FormGroup ;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
  userName: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  confirmPassword: '',
    });
  }

  register(): void{
    console.log(this.registrationForm.value);
  }
}
```

in registration component  .html

```
 <div class="container mb-4 ar">
  <h5>التسجيل</h5>
  <hr>
  <div class="login-container">
    <form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="register()">
      <!-- UserName input -->
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="UserName" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">اسم المستخدم</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input formControlName="userName" type="text" class="form-control" id="UserName" placeholder="اسم المستخدم">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Email input -->
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="Email">البريد الاليكترونى</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input formControlName="email" type="email" id="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="البريد الاليكترونى"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Password input -->
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="password">كلمة السر</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input formControlName="password" type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="كلمة السر"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ConfirmPassword input -->
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="confirmPassword"> تاكيد كلمة السر</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input formControlName="confirmPassword" type="password" id="confirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder=" تاكيد كلمة السر"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Submit button -->
      <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-2">التسجيل</button>
        <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
          <strong>primary</strong>
        </div>
        <a>لدى حساب</a>
        <a href=""> تسجيل الدخول</a>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

i works very fine but when i restarted the server i got two errors in the console
[error i received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xzbe.jpg)

when i created the form it works fine but when i stopped the server and started it again i got those errors

> core.js:4197 ERROR Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer]
> at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:3935)
> at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:13753)
> at NodeInjectorFactory.NgControlStatusGroup_Factory [as factory] (forms.js:706)
> at getNodeInjectable (core.js:4029)
> at instantiateAllDirectives (core.js:7964)
> at createDirectivesInstances (core.js:7330)
> at Module.ɵɵelementStart (core.js:13902)
> at NavBarComponent_Template (nav-bar.component.html:24)
> at executeTemplate (core.js:7303)
> at renderView (core.js:7112) defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:4197 main.ts:12 Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer]
> at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:3935)
> at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:13753)
> at NodeInjectorFactory.NgControlStatusGroup_Factory [as factory] (forms.js:706)
> at getNodeInjectable (core.js:4029)
> at instantiateAllDirectives (core.js:7964)
> at createDirectivesInstances (core.js:7330)
> at Module.ɵɵelementStart (core.js:13902)
> at NavBarComponent_Template (nav-bar.component.html:24)
> at executeTemplate (core.js:7303)
> at renderView (core.js:7112) (anonymous) @ main.ts:12 client:52 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change ngOnInit in `registration.component.ts` and import FormsModule in `app.module`

```
this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
  userName: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  confirmPassword: '',
});
```

Comment: this was the problem import FormsModule in app.module